# Preventing 'Select' and 'Select All' in UITextView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextview

I've found elsewhere that the following code prevents Copy and Paste in a UITextView. But I can't make analogous code work to prevent Select and Paste in a UITextView without totally disabling all the UITextFields.

The Select and Select All methods show up when I touch in the text field while editing. In other words, if I stop entering numbers and simply touch and hold in the field that is being edited, the Select and Select All methods pop up. I don't want that to happen. Any suggestions?

```
@implementation UITextView (DisableCopyPaste)
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem.

1) You could set the [UITextView's delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006897). The delegate contains a method (`- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView`) that you could implement to avoid selection.

2) You could also set the UITextView's property userInteractionEnabled to NO. Then it won't scroll anymore though.

Comment: Larcus, If I were to set the UITextView's property userInteractionEnabled to NO, I wouldn't be able to edit the field at all. Scrolling or not scrolling is not the problem, in part, because the text field only has one line.

Comment: Also, when the user touches a text field, the numeric keypad pops up, the background of the text field is changed to yellow, and the text in the text field is blanked. The problem I'm trying to solve arises when the user provides numerical input via the keypad and then touches inside the text field. That's when the Select and Select All methods pop up. I don't want these methods to show.